# Getting value of selected option from multiple select fields at once

Tags: javascript, jquery

Imagine having `x` amount of select fields (value of `x` is not set in stone). I would like to get values of selected option of each select fields using jQuery (or vanilla JavaScript).

My approach:

```js
var cars = $(".select").find("option:selected").val();
$(".select").on("click", function() {
  $(".show-value").html("value: " + cars);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select" name="test" id="">
  <option value="0">Ford</option>
  <option value="1">Honda</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
</select>
<select class="select" name="test" id="">
  <option value="0">Ford</option>
  <option value="1">Honda</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
</select>
<select class="select" name="test" id="">
  <option value="0">Ford</option>
  <option value="1">Honda</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
</select>
<div class="show-value"></div>
```

That is giving the first `val()`. only - I would like an array. Fun fact - when I change `val()` to `text()` it will pick up 3 'text values' without problem. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you're only reading the value from the first found selected `option` (ie. from the first `select`) when the page loads. This is why the value never appears to change. You need to read the value when a `change` event fires on the `select`.

Secondly, don't use the `click` event on `select` elements. Use `change` as I mentioned above. This is for accessibility reasons. It's also only fired when a change has been made instead of every time the options list is opened/closed.

Thirdly, you can call `val()` directly on a `select` to get its value. You don't need to use `find('option:selected')`.

Lastly, if you want an array of the `select` values you can use `map()` to build it:

```js
var $selects = $(".select");
$selects.on("change", function() {
  var cars = $selects.map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
  }).get();
  
  $('.show-value').text(cars.join(', '));
  console.log(cars);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select" name="test" id="">
  <option value="0">Ford</option>
  <option value="1">Honda</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
</select>

<select class="select" name="test" id="">
  <option value="0">Ford</option>
  <option value="1">Honda</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
</select>

<select class="select" name="test" id="">
  <option value="0">Ford</option>
  <option value="1">Honda</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
</select>

<div class="show-value"></div>
```

Comment: That is very good answer. Why would text() method give all three texts though?

Comment: It's because the `join()` call concatenates all the values in the array in to a single string separated by the `,`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: you can create values on change event of select box and push into map

```js
$(".select").on("change", function() {
   var cars = $(".select").find("option:selected").map(function() {
    return $(this).val();
   }).get().join();
   $(".show-value").html("value: " + cars);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select" name="test" id="">
        <option value="0">Ford</option>
        <option value="1">Honda</option>
        <option value="2">BMW</option>
    </select>
    
    <select class="select" name="test" id="">
        <option value="0">Ford</option>
        <option value="1">Honda</option>
        <option value="2">BMW</option>
    </select>

    
    <select class="select" name="test" id="">
        <option value="0">Ford</option>
        <option value="1">Honda</option>
        <option value="2">BMW</option>
    </select>
    
    <div class="show-value"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".select").on("change", function() {
  $(".show-value").html("value: " + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select" name="test" id="">
        <option value="0">Ford</option>
        <option value="1">Honda</option>
        <option value="2">BMW</option>
    </select>
    
    <select class="select" name="test" id="">
        <option value="0">Ford</option>
        <option value="1">Honda</option>
        <option value="2">BMW</option>
    </select>

    
    <select class="select" name="test" id="">
        <option value="0">Ford</option>
        <option value="1">Honda</option>
        <option value="2">BMW</option>
    </select>
    
    <div class="show-value"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this too.

```
 $( ".select" ).each(function( index ) {
      console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).val() );
    });
//this will return all of the dropdown selected values
```